# I have problem about memory leak caused by WindowsFormsHost in WPF

Tags: wpf

I write WPF App.

But I have some problems about memory leak caused by WindowsFormsHost.

This is Sample Code

```
public class Class1 : WindowsFormsHost{
    public Class1()
    {
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }}
```

and then called Class1 like that.

```
<Window
x:Class="WpfApp5.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="Window1"
Width="800"
Height="450"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <local:Class1 x:Name="classes" />
</Grid>
```

After Run App, I repeated action like Open window1 and close window1,
and then Check memory.
Even though GC collects memory, Class1 is alive in memory a lot.

What should I do, how do I remove Class1 from memory?

----- Add --------

[Window1 behind Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27IbO.png)

[MainWindow behid Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvlIf.png)

Comment: Use the Closed event of Window to dispose your control.

Comment: Are you just closing the window or are you disposing it? Show us the Code how you do this. Just edit your question to add it. Code in comments is to hard to read...